# Why does the compiler want a trailing return-type?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, for-loop, c++11

I was playing around with an adapter for using range-based for-loops to iterate in reverse. (I did not know about the boost adapter ("adaptor") for that purpose. I am a big believer in not re-inventing the wheel if it's a free wheel I have already downloaded.)

What puzzles me is why VC++ 2012 is not happy unless I use trailing return-types in the code that follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<class Fwd>
struct Reverser {
    const Fwd &fwd;
    Reverser<Fwd>(const Fwd &fwd_): fwd(fwd_) {}
    auto begin() -> decltype(fwd.rbegin()) const { return fwd.rbegin(); } 
    auto end() ->   decltype(fwd.rend())   const { return fwd.rend(); } 
};

template<class Fwd>
Reverser<Fwd> reverse(const Fwd &fwd) { return Reverser<Fwd>(fwd); }

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    const string str = ".dlrow olleH";
    for(char c: reverse(str)) cout << c;
    cout << endl;
}
```

When I tried the following, I got the errors, "error C2100: illegal indirection," and "error C2228: left of '.rbegin' must have class/struct/union". What am I missing?

```
template<class Fwd>
struct Reverser {
    const Fwd &fwd;
    Reverser<Fwd>(const Fwd &fwd_): fwd(fwd_) {}
    decltype(fwd.rbegin()) begin() const { return fwd.rbegin(); } 
    decltype(fwd.rend())   end() const { return fwd.rend(); } 
};
```

UPDATE: In light of the discussion about a "this" pointer, I tried another tack. Look Ma, no this! And it compiles fine. I do believe that, rightly or wrongly, VC++ is not aware of that this.

```
template<class Fwd>
struct Reverser {
    const Fwd &fwd;
    Reverser<Fwd>(const Fwd &fwd_): fwd(fwd_) {}
    decltype(((const Fwd*)0)->rbegin()) begin() const { return fwd.rbegin(); } 
    decltype(((const Fwd*)0)->rend())   end()   const { return fwd.rend(); } 

};
```

UPDATE 2: Submitted to MS: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/765455/vc-2012-compiler-refuses-decltype-return-spec-for-member-function

UPDATE 3: This problem is fixed as of VC++ 2015. Thanks, Microsoft person.

Comment: i'm not sure it has anything to do with it, but where is the return statement in you'er main function?

Comment: No return statement is required. I checked with my language lawyer.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you replace the const reference with a pointer?

Comment: @jdv I think I remember trying that, and it did not work either.

Comment: An usual way to conjure things out of thin air in unevaluated operands is e.g. `std::declval<const Fwd&>().rbegin()`.

Comment: So I contacted one of my friends on the VC++ compiler team and there's now a bug filed against this for VC 2013 =)

Comment: Note that this is fixed as of at least VC++ 2013 Update 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NOTE FROM OP: *VC++ was buggy. VC++ 2015 accepts the code correctly.*

My original answer that the code that VC++ rejected is disallowed in the standard actually was wrong: It is allowed as Johannes Schaub pointed out: in 5.1 [expr.prim.general] paragraph 12 it is described where an *id-expression* denoting a non-static data member or a non-static member function can be used. In particular, the last bullet states:

> if that id-expression denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand.

The expression in `decltype(expr)` is an unevaluated operand. Furthermore, 9.3.1 [class.mfct.non-static] paragraph 3 explains the situation where `this` is implicitly added to an expression:

> When an id-expression (5.1) that is not part of a class member access syntax (5.2.5) and not used to form a pointer to member (5.3.1) is used in a member of class X in a context where this can be used (5.1.1), if name lookup (3.4) resolves the name in the id-expression to a non-static non-type member of some class C, and if either the id-expression is potentially evaluated or C is X or a base class of X, the id-expression is transformed into a class member access expression (5.2.5) using (*this) (9.3.2) as the postfix-expression to
>   the left of the . operator.

The context in question is not "potentially evaluated" and there is no based involved. Thus, `this` isn't added and doesn't have to be in scope. Taken together, this means that the declaration

```
decltype(fwd.rbegin()) begin() const;
```

should be legal. It seems that using

```
decltype(static_cast<Reverser<Fwd> const*>(0)->fwd.rbegin()) begin() const;
```

is a work-around in cases where the compiler isn't correctly implemented.

Comment: `fwd` is in scope even outside the function definition. Other C++11 compilers handle this just fine. I'd have to look closer at the standard, but I think this is just a VC++ bug.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that VC++ is correct on this an the other compilers are wrong! What is the syntax of the out-of-line definition of `begin()` if the `decltype()` is **not** trailing?

Comment: In a conforming C++ implementation, his code is valid. There will be no `this` added, and consequently there will be no const/volatile modification added by a const/volatile member function, but that's irrelevant here. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1207

Comment: FWIW, g++ 4.7.0 compiles both of them, but if the definition of fwd is moved to the end of the struct, where many of us might put it, it won't compile either of them (which is probably a bug).

Comment: @DietmarKühl it is perfectly legal in C++11 to say `decltype(Reverser<Fwd>::fwd.rbegin())` in an out of line definition - in an unevaluated operand you don't need an object to access a non-static data member.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: doesn't this talk about the _trailing_ return type? I agree that the trailing return type works. However, if the `decltype(fwd.rbegin()` is used in front of the member declaration I don't think it is legal. I had a look through the standard and didn't find any statement either way. The resolution of the issue you quote explicitly mentions that "this may be used in the *trailing-return-type* of the declarator." Of course, this doesn't necessariy mean that it can't be used in the normal return.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Prior to allowing usage of `this` in a trailing return type, using non-static data members already worked in a trailing return type, such as in the code of 1207. I linked to 1207 to show that whether or not you are allowed to use `this` in the return type is not relevant for whether or not the code of this question is well-formed, both in a heading and trailing.

Comment: Take a peak at the UPDATE to the original question.

Comment: @Dietmar I read your revised answer. I think I remember using a pointer to the member reference, and that did not work either. Not sure though. Another workaround, which you will find now in the Question, is not to access the member reference at all, except in the function-bodies of course. If someone will tidy this up, I am ready to dispense a green check mark. Dietmar, volunteer?

Comment: @DietmarKühl See 5.1p12 last bullet and the conditions under which `this` is implicitly added at 9.3.1p3. The normal return type specification is not a place where `this` can be used, so it is not added implicitly (your answer correctly states "assuming the this pointer is in scope" :)).

Comment: @Johannes Oops. I was asking to wrap things up, but it looks as though the matter is still not settled. At least I am glad that if I was making a mistake, it was not a real obvious one.

Comment: @JiveDadson: Johannes pointed at the sections in the standard where it states that it is allowed. That is, your original code should work - my answer is wrong but this discussion seems valuable and thus I don't want to remove it. It seems to be a bug in VC++.

Comment: @Dietmar I am not asking you to remove anything. I just do not want to be the one tasked with writing the acceptable answer. I am out of my depth.

Comment: So, is everyone in agreement that the code that VC++ rejected is compliant?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: If you are stating that it should be legal to use `this` in a non-trailing return type, I am not sure about that. 5.1.1p3 states that `this` can only be used between the optional *cv-qualifier-seq* and the end of the *function-definition*, *member-declarator* or *declarator*. That seems to exclude the use in the usual return type, as that is before the *cv-qualifier-seq*. The non-trailing return type if I understand it correctly cannot refer to `this`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Johannes's point was that `this` actually isn't used by `decltype(fwd.rbegin())` while I thought it is. Based on the two quotes he provided, `this` isn't implicitly added and, thus, `decltype(fwd.rbegin())` can be used for the non-trailing return type.

Comment: @Dietmar: Let me ask in a different way. Without the implicit `this`, is the expression `fwd.begin()` inside the `decltype` legal? Note, `decltype(Reverser<Fwd>::fwd.begin())` is (or might, not 100% sure either) legal, but is `decltype(fwd.begin())` without the qualification or implicit `this` legal? My assumption is that it is not. What makes the expression legal in the trailing result case or a function definition is that there will be an implicit `(*this).` added.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Based on the two quoted sections from the C++ standard I concluded that it is legal to use `decltype(fwd.rbegin())` for the non-trailing return type, at least, for the declaration within the class definition. I don't know how a corresponding member can be defined outside the class definition.